# How To Accept Only Specific Character input from user In C

Tags: c, input, character

Is it possible to accept only specific character input from user In C?

For example:
My input from user can consist only of certain characters like `a`, `h` or `$`. The user should not be able to input characters other than `a`, `h` or `$`.
That is `"ahhaa$"` should check true, `"ahbd"` should check false.

How do I implement this in C?

Comment: What code have you tried so far, and what problem are you having?

Comment: What keeps you from just applying your rule? I.e. scan the input character by character and if you find one outside of the set return false, otherwise true. Are you asking about how to program a character loop over input? Are you asking about how to check a character against a given set? Without those explanations, your question is unclear. It also gives the impression of being a "free code writing request".

Comment: Research _scanset_  and `fscanf()`.

Comment: "The user should not be able to input characters other than 'a', 'h' or '$'"  makes me smile as I imagine C somehow making the keyboard change into a 3 key device.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the input string in hand to check, you can use `strspn`. `strspn` will return the length of the prefix of the first argument that consists entirely of characters in the second argument. Your check can then see if the returned length matches the length of the input.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool check_input(const char *input) {
    size_t n = strspn(input, "ah$");
    return input[n] == '\0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possibly to add a filter to `stdin`.  You'll need to read the input, and filter it yourself.